# vim syntax highlight only when being followed by negative words

Tags: regex, vim, syntax

I'm writing a syntax plugin which highlight certain keywords in my log.
But I had a trouble to highlight only in case of being followed by negative result word.

For example, I don't want highlight when it succeeds,

```
result:good
result:0x0000
```

However I'd like to highlight

```
result:bad
result:notready
result:0x0001
result:0xffff
result:0x0002
```

but I cannot make a regex for this negative results.
Could I request your supports, please?

PS : I've tried

```
syntax match error_result "\vresult:(good|0x0000)@!"
```

But it doesn't highlight the remaining part after :(colon).

Comment: What regex and commands have to tried so far?

Comment: I've added what I've tried. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Olaf please note that OP is asking about vim regex, so your suggestions are invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `@!` matches with *zero width*. To highlight everything after the colon, we can add `.*` (any number of any characters) after the pattern to match the rest of the line, only if the `(good|0x0000)` group *doesn't* match.

```
syntax match error_result "\vresult:(good|0x0000)@!.*"
```

If you only want the text *after* `result:` to be highlighted, but still match on the same content, add the `\zs` sequence where the match (highlighting) should start. Eg:

```
syntax match error_result "\vresult:(good|0x0000)@!\zs.*"
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to highlight just thw negative word rather than till the end of that line??

Comment: @windrg00 add the `\zs` sequence where you want the start of the match. I'll update my answer to add this.

Comment: What does \zs mean?? Thanks anyway!!

Comment: @windrg00 `:h \zs`